# Search on ListFragment with backwards compatibility

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I have a VERY similar code to [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#example) shown in the Android Dev site.

I want it to be backwards compatible to API 10 so that it supports API 10+. The example works fine from API 11+.

The example also works fine if we remove the OnQueryTextListener parts. When I add that it stops working.

So I wonder how could I have search functionality on API 10 similar to this example.

Thanks.